# C getchar() and EOF behavior

Tags: c, input, eof, getchar, ctrl

I am reading The C Programming Language (K & R) and playing with the code having some hard time understanding behavior of `getchar()` function and related `EOF` macro.
Environment: Windows 10 (Ctrl-Z as EOF).

Here's a very simple code snippet I'm playing with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    printf("Enter something:\n");
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("End\n");
}
```

1. When I run it and input something it works very well (simple duplicate of the input):

```
Enter something:
hello world
hello world
a
a
a
a
```

2. However, when I provide some input with `EOF` (Ctrl-Z) at the end, the loop doesn't end for some reason, I've got a right arrow character. Why is that so?

```
Enter something:
hellow world^Z
hellow world→
```

Doesn't C have to read each single character and find Ctrl-Z to end the loop?

3. In order to end the loop I have to provide Ctrl-Z on the separate line:

```
Enter something:
hellow world^Z
hellow world→^Z
End
```

or:

```
Enter something:
hello world     
hello world     
^Z              
End
```

4. What really bizarres me is a situation when I provide Ctrl-Z at the middle of the input - only a half of the input is printed:

```
Enter something:
hello^Zworld
hello→
```

And loop doesn't stop.

I would really appriciate any description of the provided behavior.

**P.S**: please, do not mark this post as duplicate. I know that there are tonn of similar discussions on this topic, but all of them don't really answer my questions.

Comment: Ctrl-Z for Windows, Ctrl-D for Linux. With Windows, the Ctrl-Z must be between two newlines.

Comment: @CuriousPanCake: "and related EOR macro." --> do you mean "and related EOF macro."?

Comment: @CuriousPanCake "when I provide some input with EOF (Ctrl-Z) at the end" --> Typing ^Z after "hellow world" is _not_ an `EOF`.